# Why Postman recive the express session cookie but not my post request in my React app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, postman, express-session

I have a nodejs server with express, express-session and passport for authentification. My login route look like this:

```js
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
  return res.status(200).json({
    message: "Auth successful",
    username: req.user.username
  })
})
```

When I test the route with Postman I receive the cookie with the session id in the response: [Postman result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLlgq.png) But when I do a post request with axios in React I don't recive any cookies:

```js
const login = (email, password) => {
    const reqBody = {
        email,
        password
    }

    const config = {
        withCredentials : true,
    }

    return axios.post(`${serverUrl}/user/login`, reqBody, config)
}
```

Here are my cors in my Node.js server:

```js
// Cors definition 
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE')
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)

  next()
})
```

[Network tab on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMzpa.png) As you can see there is no cookies tab in the console and noting in the headers. So I want to know why and how can I fix this.

Comment: This seems like a cross origin issue are you hosting your site on `localhost:4200` or something and server is on another port not 4200

Comment: My cors headers are set up on my server and I receive the status 200 with the message and the username in my React app. If it was a cross origin issue, would I not be able to make a request at all? To answer your questions, my server is on port 5000 and my client on port 3000.

Comment: Can you post the headers you are using for cross origin, since there is some additional headers that you may want to set to preserve cookies

Comment: I added the headers I've set on my server in my question as you asked.

Answer (score 1):

So! I kinda found the answer to why I can see the cookie in Postman response but not my browser (Chrome). I found the cookie in chrome, not in *application -> Storage -> Cookies* in the console of the page but in *chrome://settings/cookies/detail?site=192.168.2.89* .

What I understood is express-session or postman.session() set http only on the cookie:

> Using the HttpOnly flag when generating a cookie helps mitigate the risk of client side script accessing the protected cookie (if the browser supports it). https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

I was still not able to see where express was setting the headers and how to log cookies sent by the server.

Answer (score 0):

cookies do not come in the response, they come in the header. please look in the header you should have an entry that is 'Set-Cookie'

Comment: If the set-cookie header is there Chrome will add the cookies tab.

Comment: have you tried to eliminate postman's cookies? Maybe he returns the cookie in the postman because he is sending it

Comment: yeah, I removed all the cookies and created a new request just to be sure and he still gets it.